# Setting cookie with JWT token works fine in postman, appears in devtools, but cannot get it in backend (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

The problem is that I cannot get the cookie in the server. It is set in the browser (I can see it in devtools). When using Postman it works fine (including the middleware). But for some reason when making the request from the browser to the middleware (authMiddleware) the token comes back undefined.

Anyone with any ideas would be great. I have been stuck on this for **days**! :O

***App.js (server)***

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const authRouter = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const cocktailRouter = require('./routes/cocktailRoutes');
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(process.env.DBURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('listening');
        app.listen(5000)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

//middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

// ROUTER MIDDLEWARE
app.use('/api/cocktails', cocktailRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
```

***authMiddleware***

```
const User = require('../models/User');
require('dotenv').config();

//check user is authorized 
const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    console.log('TOKEN', token)

    //check json web token exists and is verified
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                // res.redirect('/auth/login');
                console.log('not logged in')
            } else {
                console.log('logged in ')
                next();
            }
        })
    } else {
        // res.redirect('/auth/login');
        console.log('not logged in again')
    }
};

module.exports = { requireAuth };
```

***cocktailRoute***
This is where I am implementing the requireAuth middleware:

```
const router = Router();
const { requireAuth } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware');

const { cocktail_get, cocktail_post, cocktail_put, cocktail_delete } = require('../controllers/cocktailController');

router.get('/', requireAuth, cocktail_get);
router.post('/', cocktail_post);
router.put('/:cocktailId', cocktail_put);
router.delete('/:cocktailId', cocktail_delete);

module.exports = router;
```

***authController***

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

//handle errors function
const handleErrors = (err) => {
    const { message } = err;
    const errors = { email: '', password: '' }

    //incorrect email
    if (message === 'Incorrect email') {
        errors.email = 'Invalid email';
    };

    //incorrect password
    if (message === 'Incorrect password') {
        errors.password = 'Invalid password';
    };

    //duplicate error = 11000
    if (err.code === 11000) {
        errors.email = 'That email is already registered';
        return errors;
    }

    //validation errors
    if (message.includes('user validation failed')) {
        Object.values(err.errors).forEach(({ properties }) => {
            errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
        })
    };
    return errors;
}

//create jwt token 
const maxAge = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3 days in seconds
const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: maxAge })
};

module.exports.register_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.create({ name, email, password });
        const token = createToken(user._id);
        res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: false, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
        res.status(201).json({ user: user._id, token });
    } catch (err) {
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
};

module.exports.login_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.login(email, password);
        const token = createToken(user._id);
        res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: false, maxAge: maxAge * 1000, secure: false });
        res.status(200).json({ user: user._id });
    } catch (err) {
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
};

module.exports.logout_get = (req, res) => {
    console.log(res.cookie('jwt', '', { maxAge: 1 }))
    res.cookie('jwt', '', { maxAge: 1 });
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

***FRONTEND (React)***
***LoginPage***

```
const LoginPage = () => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
    };

    const handleLoginFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = values;
        try {
            fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/login`, {
                method: "POST",
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email, password
                })
            })
        } catch (err) { if (err.request) { console.log('REQUEST', err.request) } if (err.response) { console.log('RESPONSE', err.response) } }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleLoginFormSubmit}>
                <input type="text" value={values.email} name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" onChange={handleChange} />
                <input type="password" value={values.password} name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" onChange={handleChange} />
                <button>Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginPage
```

Comment: What kind of _sameSite_ cookie do you use? Is it strict? Do you run your front-end and back-end on same domain (like _front.myproject.devel_ and _back.myproject.devel_)? Browser might be blocking cookies in cross-origin and unsecured environment.

Comment: @Jax-p

I am still a little new to cookies etc. What do you mean by sameSite? 
I am running my backend on http://localhost:5000 and frontend on http://localhost:3000. I have used cors to deal with this problem though. Plus my api calls seem to be working fine. I.e I can register a user etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you see that token in browser (check it directly in browser, http cookies are not accessible from js)? Check [sameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) cookie in [network](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/) tab in _devtools_ and check possible warnings (small yellow exclamation mark). You can also [try to disable some security features](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug) for testing.

Comment: @Jax-p Yes I can see the jwt token in the devtools. I can also get the cookie via - document.cookies.. There are no warnings. I feel like the problem is that I am not sending the cookie back... Could it be something to do with my header both in node and also react when I make the API call requests?

Comment: @Jax-p 
I have just checked and I can see that in my devtools the cookie is set to sameSite: none and secure: true. Also, I can see the cookie in the request headers in the devtools. Does this help?